# same property and method return different values

Tags: kotlin, methods, properties

I have following code in fragment:

```
   override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_packs,container,false)
        view.doOnLayout {
            val f1=isRemoving         //false
            val f2=context==null      //false
            val f3=activity == null   //false
            val f4=isDetached         //false
            val f5=!isAdded           //false
            val f6= this.view == null //false
            val safe1=isSafe          //false
            val safe2=isSafe()        //true(!!!)
            if(isSafe) {
                init()
            }
        }
        return view
    }

    private val isSafe: Boolean=!(isRemoving || context==null || activity == null || isDetached || !isAdded || view == null)

    private fun isSafe(): Boolean=!(isRemoving || context==null || activity == null || isDetached || !isAdded || view == null)
```

I got values in the comments from the debugger.`isSafe` and `isSafe()` contains identical logic.How can they return different values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the expression assigned to `isSafe` is evaluated when the fragment instance is constructed and remains unchanged after that, while the return value of `isSafe()` is evaluated anew each time it is called.

Comment: ough indeed this is not a getter